# Any better/faster way to calculate the relative rank of each element in an array?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, sorting, rank

I want to calculate the relative rank of each element in an array among elements before it. For example in an array `[2,1,4,3]`, the relative rank (from small to large) of the second element (`1`) among a subset array of `[2,1]` is `1`. The relative rank of the third element (`4`) among a subset array of `[2,1,4]` is `3`. The final relative rank of each element should be `[1,1,3,3]`.

I'm using the following python code:

```
x = np.array([2,1,4,3])
rr = np.ones(4)
for i in range(1,4):
    rr[i] = sum(x[i] >= x[:i+1])
```

Are there any other faster ways?

Comment: I can vouch for the Ranking library. https://pypi.org/project/ranking/

Comment: @AKX: That does something completely different.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Read the question a bit too fast...

Comment: The classic algorithm for this is an inversion-tracking mergesort. I'm too sleepy to be able to give a good explanation right now, but Googling it should turn up useful resources.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's faster, but you can do this with a list comprehension, which always brightens my day:

```
[sorted(x[:i+1]).index(v)+1 for i, v in enumerate(x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized way with `broadcasting` -

```
n = len(x)
m1 = x[1:,None]>=x
m2 = np.tri(n-1,n,k=1, dtype=bool)
rr[1:] = (m1 & m2).sum(1)
```

Alternatively, we could bring in `einsum` or `np.matmul` to do the last step of `sum-reduction` -

```
(m1.astype(np.float32)[:,None,:] @ m2[:,:,None])[:,0,0]
np.einsum('ij,ij->i',m1.astype(np.float32),m2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current algorithm takes quadratic time, which isn't going to scale to large inputs. You can do a lot better.

One way to do better would be to use a sorted data structure, like [`sortedcontainers.SortedList`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html), and perform a series of lookups and insertions. The following example implementation returns a list, assumes no ties, and starts ranks from 0:

```
import sortedcontainers

def rank(nums):
    sortednums = sortedcontainers.SortedList()
    ranks = []
    for num in nums:
        ranks.append(sortednums.bisect_left(num))
        sortednums.add(num)
    return ranks
```

Most of the work is inside the `SortedList` implementation, and `SortedList` is pretty fast, so this shouldn't have too much Python overhead. The existence of `sortedcontainers` definitely makes this more convenient than the next option, if not necessarily more efficient.

This option runs in... O(n log n)-ish time. `SortedList` uses a two-layer hierarchy instead of a traditional tree structure, making a deliberate tradeoff of more data movement for less pointer chasing, so insertion isn't theoretically O(log n), but it's efficient in practice.

---

The next option would be to use an augmented mergesort. If you do this, you're going to want to use Numba or Cython, because you'll have to write the loops manually.

The basic idea is to do a mergesort, but tracking the rank of each element in its subarray as you go. When you merge two sorted subarrays, each element on the left side keeps its old rank, while the rank values for elements on the right side get adjusted upward for how many elements on the left were less than them.

This option runs in O(n log n).

An unoptimized implementation operating on Python lists, assuming no ties, and starting ranks at 0, would look like this:

```
def rank(nums):
    _, indexes, ranks = _augmented_mergesort(nums)
    result = [None]*len(nums)
    for i, rank_ in zip(indexes, ranks):
        result[i] = rank_
    return result

def _augmented_mergesort(nums):
    # returns sorted nums, indexes of sorted nums in original nums, and corresponding ranks
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return nums, [0], [0]
    left, right = nums[:len(nums)//2], nums[len(nums)//2:]
    return _merge(*_augmented_mergesort(left), *_augmented_mergesort(right))

def _merge(lnums, lindexes, lranks, rnums, rindexes, rranks):
    nums, indexes, ranks = [], [], []
    i_left = i_right = 0

    def add_from_left():
        nonlocal i_left
        nums.append(lnums[i_left])
        indexes.append(lindexes[i_left])
        ranks.append(lranks[i_left])
        i_left += 1
    def add_from_right():
        nonlocal i_right
        nums.append(rnums[i_right])
        indexes.append(rindexes[i_right] + len(lnums))
        ranks.append(rranks[i_right] + i_left)
        i_right += 1

    while i_left < len(lnums) and i_right < len(rnums):
        if lnums[i_left] < rnums[i_right]:
            add_from_left()
        elif lnums[i_left] > rnums[i_right]:
            add_from_right()
        else:
            raise ValueError("Tie detected")

    if i_left < len(lnums):
        nums += lnums[i_left:]
        indexes += lindexes[i_left:]
        ranks += lranks[i_left:]
    else:
        while i_right < len(rnums):
            add_from_right()

    return nums, indexes, ranks
```

For an optimized implementation, you'd want an insertion sort base case, you'd want to use Numba or Cython, you'd want to operate on arrays, and you'd want to not do so much allocation.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explaination. I will try to understand each of your suggested algorithm and the first one is the best so far among all replies!

Comment: I tried your second algorithm, it is not as good as your first one. I also tried to apply your algorithms to 2D array, but their performance is not satisfactory compared with numy array calculation. See my new post for 2D array tests.

Comment: @John: The second implementation is unoptimized. You'd have to rewrite it with Cython or Numba to see better performance. As for the 2D case, you weren't supposed to do both `(m1.astype(np.float32)[:,None,:] @ m2[:,:,None])[:,0,0]` *and* `np.einsum('ij,ij->i',m1.astype(np.float32),m2)` in Divarkar's version.

Comment: thanks for reply. I will try to learn how to write code for numba. I'm newbie in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You are all my hero! doing great job!. I'd like to show you the comparison of each of your solution:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import sortedcontainers

def John(x):
    n=len(x)
    rr=np.ones(n)
    for i in range(1,n):
        rr[i]=sum(x[i]>=x[:i+1])
    return rr

def Matvei(x):
    return [sorted(x[:i+1]).index(v)+1 for i, v in enumerate(x)]

def Divarkar1(x):
    n = len(x)
    m1 = x[1:,None]>=x
    m2 = np.tri(n-1,n,k=1, dtype=bool)
    rr[1:] = (m1 & m2).sum(1)
    return rr


def Divarkar2(x):
    n = len(x)
    m1 = x[1:,None]>=x
    m2 = np.tri(n-1,n,k=1, dtype=bool)
    (m1.astype(np.float32)[:,None,:] @ m2[:,:,None])[:,0,0]
    rr[1:]=np.einsum('ij,ij->i',m1.astype(np.float32),m2)
    return rr

def Monica(x):
    sortednums = sortedcontainers.SortedList()
    ranks = []
    for num in x:
        ranks.append(sortednums.bisect_left(num))
        sortednums.add(num)
    return np.array(ranks)+1


x=np.random.rand(4000)

t1=time.time()
rr=John(x)
t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)
#print(rr)

t1=time.time()
rr=Matvei(x)
t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)
#print(rr)

t1=time.time()
rr=Divarkar1(x)
t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)
#print(rr)

t1=time.time()
rr=Divarkar2(x)
t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)
#print(rr)

t1=time.time()
rr=Monica(x)
t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)
#print(rr)
```

The results are:

19.5

2.9

0.079

0.25

0.017

I ran several times and results are similar. The best one is Monica's algorithm!

Many thanks to everyone!

John

Comment: I would like to see how my solutions compare using your benchmarks if you have a time to add to this post.

Answer (score 0):

when I converted all algorithms into numpy 2D array, I found my algorithm is the best. Of course the performance also depends on the dimension of 2D array. But 380x900 is my case. I think Numpy array calculation benefits it a lot. Here are codes:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import sortedcontainers
def John(x): #x is 1D array
    n=len(x)
    rr=[]
    for i in range(n):
        rr.append(np.sum(x[i]>=x[:i+1]))
    return np.array(rr)

def John_2D(rv): #rv is 2d numpy array. rank it along axis 1!
    nr,nc=rv.shape
    rr=[]
    for i in range(nc):
        rr.append(np.sum((rv[:,:i+1]<=rv[:,i:i+1]),axis=1))
    return np.array(rr).T

def Matvei(x): #x is 1D array
    return [sorted(x[:i+1]).index(v)+1 for i, v in enumerate(x)]

def Divarkar1(x):#x is 1D array
    n = len(x)
    rr=np.ones(n,dtype=int)
    m1 = x[1:,None]>=x
    m2 = np.tri(n-1,n,k=1, dtype=bool)
    rr[1:] = (m1 & m2).sum(1)
    return rr

def Divarkar2(x):#x is 1D array
    n = len(x)
    rr=np.ones(n,dtype=int)
    m1 = x[1:,None]>=x
    m2 = np.tri(n-1,n,k=1, dtype=bool)
    (m1.astype(np.float32)[:,None,:] @ m2[:,:,None])[:,0,0]
    rr[1:]=np.einsum('ij,ij->i',m1.astype(np.float32),m2)
    return rr

def Monica1(nums): #nums is 1D array
    sortednums = sortedcontainers.SortedList()
    ranks = []
    for num in nums:
        ranks.append(sortednums.bisect_left(num))
        sortednums.add(num)
    return np.array(ranks)+1

def Monica2(nums): #nums is 1D array
    _, indexes, ranks = _augmented_mergesort(nums)
    result = [None]*len(nums)
    for i, rank_ in zip(indexes, ranks):
        result[i] = rank_
    return np.array(result)+1

def _augmented_mergesort(nums): #nums is 1D array
    # returns sorted nums, indexes of sorted nums in original nums, and corresponding ranks
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return nums, [0], [0]
    left, right = nums[:len(nums)//2], nums[len(nums)//2:] #split the array by half
    return _merge(*_augmented_mergesort(left), *_augmented_mergesort(right))

def _merge(lnums, lindexes, lranks, rnums, rindexes, rranks):
    nums, indexes, ranks = [], [], []
    i_left = i_right = 0

    def add_from_left():
        nonlocal i_left
        nums.append(lnums[i_left])
        indexes.append(lindexes[i_left])
        ranks.append(lranks[i_left])
        i_left += 1
    def add_from_right():
        nonlocal i_right
        nums.append(rnums[i_right])
        indexes.append(rindexes[i_right] + len(lnums))
        ranks.append(rranks[i_right] + i_left)
        i_right += 1

    while i_left < len(lnums) and i_right < len(rnums):
        if lnums[i_left] < rnums[i_right]:
            add_from_left()
        elif lnums[i_left] > rnums[i_right]:
            add_from_right()
        else:
            raise ValueError("Tie detected")

    if i_left < len(lnums):
        while i_left < len(lnums):
            add_from_left()
        #nums += lnums[i_left:]
        #indexes += lindexes[i_left:]
        #ranks += lranks[i_left:]
    else:
        while i_right < len(rnums):
            add_from_right()
    return nums, indexes, ranks

def rank_2D(f,nums): #f is method, nums is 2D numpy array
    result=[]
    for x in nums:
        result.append(f(x))
    return np.array(result)

x=np.random.rand(6000)
for f in [John, Matvei, Divarkar1, Divarkar2, Monica1, Monica2]:
    t1=time.time()
    rr=f(x)
    t2=time.time()
    print(f'{f.__name__+"_1D: ":16}  {(t2-t1):.3f}')
print()

x=np.random.rand(380,900)
t1=time.time()
rr=John_2D(x)
t2=time.time()
print(f'{"John_2D:":16}  {(t2-t1):.3f}')
#print(rr)

for f in [Matvei, Divarkar1, Divarkar2, Monica1, Monica2]:
    t1=time.time()
    rr=rank_2D(f,x)
    t2=time.time()
    print(f'{f.__name__+"_2D: ":16}  {(t2-t1):.3f}')
    #print(rr)
```

The typical results are:

```
John_1D:          0.069
Matvei_1D:        7.208
Divarkar1_1D:     0.163
Divarkar2_1D:     0.488
Monica1_1D:       0.032
Monica2_1D:       0.082

John_2D:          0.409
Matvei_2D:        49.044
Divarkar1_2D:     1.276
Divarkar2_2D:     4.065
Monica1_2D:       1.090
Monica2_2D:       3.571
```

For 1D array, Monica1 method is the best, but my numpy-version method is not too bad.
For 2D array, my numpy-version method is the best.

Welcome to test and comment.

Thanks

John

Comment: That's strange. You said your code was taking 19.5 seconds on an array of 4000 numbers before, but now it's only taking 0.069 seconds on an array of 6000 numbers? The change from a list to an array for `rr` wouldn't account for that. Something's wrong.

Comment: I see you also switched to `np.sum`. That could be it.

Comment: yes, I changed it to numpy calculation, which is naturally for 2D array, and improved the performance dramatically!